# pickRandom is not defined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

```
{
    var word = pickRandom([
      'Quacks' ,
      'eats',
      'Hoots',
    ]);

    print('the owl' + word + 'at midnight');
}
```

I've seen examples use arrays this way, but when I plug it in into my coding software , either nothing appears or it claims that pickRandom is undefined 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* Apparently not defining a function called `pickRandom`.

Comment: If you think you *are* defining it in your code, then post your code, else it'll be pretty impossible to debug.

Comment: `pickRandom()` is not a standard Javascript function. If you've seen this in examples, they must be defining it themselves. You need to copy that definition.

Answer (score 0):

pickRandom isn't a real function! Print doesn't exist in Javascript! Here is how to do it :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        function pickRandom() {
        var wordsarray= ['Quacks', 'eats', 'Hoats'];
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsarray.length);
        document.write(wordsarray[randomnumber]);
    }
    </script>
    <button value="clickme" onclick="pickRandom()">Click Me To Pick A Random Word!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a *pickRandom* function:

```
function pickRandom(warray){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * warray.length);
    return warray[randomNumber];
}
var words=['Quacks',
           'eats',
           'Hoots'];
var random=pickRandom(words);
console.log(random);
```